# ILMerge into nuget package causing issue with Parameter Type Mismatch with consuming project

Tags: c#, dll, namespaces, ilmerge, mismatch

I have a service dll, which has a reference to System.Web.OData (from Microsoft.AspNet.OData.5.9.0)

The service dll has an exposed method which takes in an OData.Delta<>
This service dll when compiled is ilmerged, so it has this "version" of Data embedded.

Now the consuming application, also has a reference to the same OData, however, it comes from a corext, globalized cache.

However, when the consuming application, attempts to call the method that has an OData.Delta<> parameter, it complains that it cannot convert from ConsumingApp.OData.Delta to ServiceDll.OData.Delta.

How would I go about making sure that the parameter uses the actual proper "version" of OData.Delta so that they do not conflict?

I can't seem to find like.. a NameSpace.For.ServiceDll that would enable me to specifically target the OData.Delta that is embedded in the ilmerge

Answer (score 0):

you have to install ms odata client for visual studio create a new odata client class, an add in http uri metadata de correct http. After that click on the file and run custom tool option download de latest metadata

Comment: Sorry I do not see how that solves my problem at all. What does that have to do with a type mismatch between an ilmerged dll that has the same dll in it, as an application that consumes this ilmerged dll, but also references a match dll that is embedded in the ilmerged dll...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I understood that had problems with odata schema. The error you expose, if I understood well you are using ilmerge for combine various project and reference again the library combined. I think:

1. you can add the namespace with a surname, for example:

   import reference1 = microsoft.data;
   import reference2 = ilmerge...;

so you can use them in code like reference1.class1 and reference2.class1

Hope this help you